# Trying to call Maps into parameters but unable to work

Tags: scala, akka

Hey I'm new to the language and trying to make a map that contains values used alot within the code, but currently having trouble calling the map into a parameter.

heres and example of what it looks like

```
val abcd = "abc"
val defg = "123"
val ghij = "456"

val map1 = Map ( "abcd" -> abcd, "defg" -> defg, "ghij" -> ghij)
```

that part is fine but when i want to add them all to the parameter it says there is too many arguments?

Comment: "calling the map into a parameter" this phrase doesn't make sense.

Comment: "i want to add them all to the parameter", what parameter? Why don't you show us the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

had to add

```
.toString
.##()
```

to the end of the strings and ints, for example

```
val settings = Array( map1("defg").##() );
```